# Liferay 7 : Unable find model com.liferay.journal.model.impl.JournalArticleImpl

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

When I write below line in `render` method of my custom portlet it throws the above exception.

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class);
```

I have also try using below method :

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
```

I have also added below dependency in `build.gradle` file

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.api", version: "2.2.2"
```

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Stack Trace is as below.

Render Method is called.....

```
06:42:56,450 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8][DynamicQueryFactoryImpl:103] Unable find model com.liferay.journal.model.impl.JournalArticleImpl
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.journal.model.impl.JournalArticleImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
```

Comment: since DXP the journal articles are separately deployed  and not in portal-service anymore, so you are have to import them adequately .. the interface is in the api bundle  and the implementation is in another bundle .. you have to import dem both ... since the implementation is needed at runtime you might have to declare it directly in your BND file

Comment: .. so sum that up: portalclassloader won't do it .. since they aren't in kernel anymore

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, please try:

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery( );
```

Answer (score 0):

The artifact you need to add is called

```
com.liferay.journal.service
```

Add the proper version to your `build.gradle` and build again